# "on my own way" or "in my own way"?

Tags: prepositions

> I capture and edit on my own way

Or should it be "in my own way"?

Comment: Things are done ***in*** a [specific] way, not ***on*** a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's "I capture and edit in my own way" though you should probably add what it is also.
"I capture and edit video in my own way" (assuming it's video)

Implied information, should be avoided unless it's obvious what it is.